# facebook like button comment box won't close on submit, and doesn't post anything

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins

Trying to integrate a facebook social like button plugin with the comment box. The like/unlike function works fine, and it reflects properly in my activity log on Facebook. 
However, once I type in a comment in the comment box and click "post to facebook", nothing happens! The comment box won't close when I submit, and it doesn't publish anything in the timeline.

I can see the post request in Firefox debugger. Facebook debugger doesn't report any errors on the page, and extracts the meta tags.

See my code below: What am I doing wrong or missing?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US"
  xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
  xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# website: http://ogp.me/ns/website#">

    <meta property="og:title" content="mytitle" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="mydescription" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/welcome"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/images/screen_shot_general.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="myname" />
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxxxxxxxx" />

</head>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
           window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
            appId      : 'xxxxxx', // App ID
            channelUrl : '<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>/channel.html', // Channel File
            status     : true, // check login status
            cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
            });

            // Additional initialization code here

        };


        // Load the SDK Asynchronously

        (function(d){
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
        }(document));                

   </script>    

<div class="fb-like" data-href="<?php echo $this->baseUrl(); ?>" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="90" data-show-faces="false" data-font="lucida grande"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably just a Facebook Plugin bug and it's not your code that's affecting the plugin, since it's loaded within an iframe. Are you still getting the issue? If you are, it's best to [report the bug to Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/) or see if there is an existing bug that relates to the issue.